# i want to redirect from login_view to student_view

Tags: django, django-views

i want when any user login to my site that will automatically redirected to student_view from login_view.

i have tried by return **student_view(request)** but this did not solve my problem

```
def student_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = Student_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Sucessfully Done We will Get You Soon')
    else:
        form = Student_Form()
        return render(request, 'student_detail.html', {'form':form})


def login_view(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    w="Welcome"
    title = "Login"
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return render(request,'app/index1.html',{'username':username,'w':w})

    return render(request, "app/login.html", {"form":form, "title":title})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'redirect' from Django shortcuts like this :

```
    from django.shortcuts import redirect

    def login_view(request):
        print(request.user.is_authenticated())
        w="Welcome"
        title = "Login"
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('student_view')

        return render(request, "app/login.html", {"form":form, "title":title})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can redirect to student_view after success login...

```
login(request, user)
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('your_app:your_view'))
```

Comment: what to import for this

Comment: because it is showing global name reverse is not defined

Comment: @mandeepthakur Please look prakhar answer that will help you.

Comment: @RajaSimon,Your answer is also correct.Here is my upvote :)